# Requiring a file in dragon ruby toolkit

Tags: ruby, dragonruby-game-toolkit

The usual ruby way of requiring a file seems not to work. My folder structure looks like:

> - mygame
>
>   - app
>
>     - main.rb
>     - new_file.rb

However requiring new_file in main.rb fails.

```rb
# main.rb
require './new_file.rb' # This errors out
```

The file that's getting executed is 'main.rb' and my assumption is that rootpath is app.

Comment: This cannot be answered without knowing what the current working directory is.

Comment: Will edit the question @JörgWMittag , thanks

Answer (score 2):

**root** is always *mygame* and this is why the require was not resolving correctly.

The following will work:

```rb
# main.rb
require 'app/new_file.rb' # This errors out
```

Thanks to [amir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40914/amir) for the answer in discord.